# How to change authorisation mechanism for AWS (ec2-upload-bundle)

Tags: amazon-ec2, bundle, amazon-ami, vpc

I am currently trying to back up my EC2 instance using the Amazon ec2-api-tools and ec2-ami-tools tools utilities.

I am using a standard Ubuntu 14.04 AMI from Amazon.

To download and install the required utilities, I've updated `/etc/apt/sources` with the following:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
```

I can now bundle the image as expected, however when I try to upload the AMI to a bucket I receive the following error:

```
The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
```

I am using the Frankfurt data center. From research online it seems the newer centers as per January 2014 do not support older authentication schemes.

I've tried following the guide at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingAWSSDK.html to enabled V4, however when I attempt to update my CLI config I receive the following error:

```
root@ip-10-0-1-54:/mnt/bundle# aws configure set default.s3.signature_version s3v4
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [parameters]
aws: error: argument subcommand: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

list
```

How can I fix there errors so I can back up my bundle to S3?

Comment: a year later and the problem is still there... Thinking switching to Ireland is the easy way out

Answer (score 1):

The ec2-ami-tools package in the Ubuntu 14.04 repository is outdated. The version in the repository is only version 1.4.0. Frankfurt support was only added in [version 1.5.6](https://aws.amazon.com/items/368?externalID=368&categoryID=88). The newer version of the tool should work in the Frankfurt region.

This tool is only necessary if you plan on creating instance store-backed AMIs. If your instance is EBS-backed and you need to make an AMI from it, using the AWS CLI will be much easier.